# T-SQL unfinished transaction lock

Tags: t-sql

I tried to run the following query

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION t1
SET IDENTITY_INSERT existingTableA On
insert INTO existingTableA (columnsFromTableA)
SELECT (columnsFromIdenticalTableB) from column identicalTableB
```

problem is that I didn't commit the transaction explicitly and it appears that I cannot do it any more and it's still ongoing. the select operation from tableA never ends because of the lock I cannot kill ("Distributed transaction with UOW {2B9A3B1B-F3EF-4C5A-9AD8-F434EF9EA3EC} is in prepared state. Only Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator can resolve this transaction. KILL command failed.")

how do I end that transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run DBCC OPENTRAN.

Then kill the open Transaction with KILL xx, where xx is the SPID.

Comment: how do I get spid of transaction though?

Comment: Never before have I received the correct answer to my question on stackoverflow in such a short time :D

Comment: @KamilMilkaJanowski Thanks :) Glad to be of help.